# Ridge regression in Matlab produces different results than direct calculation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to run Ridge regression in Matlab (ridge): `L` is some **matrix**, `x` is some **random vector** and `y=Lx+αn` is another **vector**. I expect `ridge(y,L,α)` to return the same result as:

`(LL'+α^2I)^(−1)L'y`, but the latter is significantly better. I can't understand the problem as I think this is exactly what `ridge()` does. I even tried with `α=1`.

For example:

```
n = randn(N^2,1);
n2 = randn(N^2,1);
L = (some N^2*N^2 matrix);
y = L*n + n2;
x_ridge = ridge(y,L,1); 
x_ls = (L*L' + eye(N^2))^-1*L'*y;
```

and `x_ls` and `x_ridge` are significantly different.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: simply put, your formula is wrong and numerically unstable. That might be why they are different.

Comment: Thanks. I found out what was wrong, apparently in Matlab I need to multiply `k` by the number of pixels to have equivalence.